# Eclipse - Problems saving workspace

Tags: eclipse

Periodically (during autosave) and at close i get:

**Problems saving workspace**

```
(X) Problems occurred while trying to save the state of the workbench.

Details >>
  Could not write metadata for '/projectname'. 
  encoded string too long: 123456 bytes
```

Can't find a reason or solution for this using the usual means. Any ideas how to fix?
THis is using eclipse 3.4 (Ganymede)

Answer (score 1):

It should relate to a bug in [DataOuputStream](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.java.html) that it cannot writeUTF with longer then 65535 utflen.

If I were you, I will try to find a way to reduce the data size, and I will submit bug report to Eclipse and JRE.

Answer (score 1):

Started having the same issues under Vista x64. The [latest JRE](http://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp) appears to not have the same DataOuputStream limitation so installing it fixes the annoyance.

Comment: Bizarre. Out of nowhere the issue is back. Oh well, I have largely switched to Komodo since then =)

Comment: This same bug is still around in Java 6u15 on XP 32-bit under Eclipse Ganymede.  I'm tempted to switch to Galileo to fix it, but since my project manager mandates which version we use, I can't.

Answer (score 0):

An observation I've made about these occurrences for me is that they only occur on newly created projects during the same Eclipse session that I created the project.  Once I restart Eclipse, I don't see the issue again until the next time I create a new project.

Has anyone else noticed this about the occurrences of the error for them?

Answer (score -1):

It's not a write permissions or disk-space issue.  I'm getting the same problem on Eclipse 3.5 M4.  No troubles with 3.4.1.